# webpage whites out when scrolling up or down

Tags: html, css, css-animations

https://habitat-commons.herokuapp.com/

When you scroll up or down on this site the divs white out and rerender no matter how fast the internet or how many times i do it. Based on other posts these are the things a checked.

1. Overflows - disabled them all and the issue remained
2. Animations - disabled them all and the issue remained
3. Scroll animations - disabled them all and the issue remained
4. filter-blur - disabled them all and the issue remained

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the problem on another device too? Because if I visit the website, everything renders normal.